# How to add a swipe gesture from left to right and add three buttons in that?

Tags: objective-c

I have a view controller having a table view in which cells are added and i need to crate a swipe gesture with three buttons in that to edit ,move and delete the content of cell.
Here is my code-

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [word count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    WordList *cell;

    cell = (WordList *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {

        if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WordCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }else{
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WordCell_ipad" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 33.0 green: 66.0 blue: 99.0 alpha: 1.0];
    cell.word.text = [word objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.meaning.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"meaning: %@",[meaning objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: For this type of controls you can search for "swipeable tableview cell" there are lots of controls are available.

Comment: Any feedback on provided answer would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For now, Apple only provide standard "Delete" and "More" button. The reset, you should implement yourself. Here is the great [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views)

Or, you can use [third-party solution](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) or [another](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell). I've used the former one, but the second looks cool too

Comment: Could you send me a tutorial of swipe gesture having 3 buttons

Comment: @poojabhasin If you check links in my answer, you'll find everything you need